# Mass edit ISingleResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, edit

I got a stored procedure which i show in the view for edits. I made a strong type of the stored procedure. When i edit the fields and then press the save button, the parameter "cm" is always empty. And it's not showing a list but just 1 record.

The custom model:

```
public class CustomModel
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<GetItems_ListResult> ItemList { get; set;}
    }
```

This part of the controller sends it to the view:

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
 {
    var row = dataContext.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == id);
    var cm = new CustomModel();
    cm.ItemList = dataContext.GetItem_List(row);
    cm.Description = row.Description;

    return View(cm);
 }
```

This controller receives data from the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItems(CustomModel cm)
{

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is the view:

```
@model TestWeb.Models.CustomModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateItems", "Item", FormMethod.Post))
{

     <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        @foreach (var p in Model.ItemList.ToList())
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(mdl => p.ItemId)
                </td>
                <td>@p.Name</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(mdl => p.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    </p>
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Make a `GetItems_ListResult.cshtml` like this:

```
<tr>
 <td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(mdl => mdl.ItemId)
 </td>
  <td>@Model.Name</td>
 <td>
    @Html.EditorFor(mdl => mdl.Description)
 </td>
</tr>
```

Then in your for loop do this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ItemList.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemsList[i])
}
```

**Update:** I didn't quite notice you were using an ISingleResult. You could do this instead:

```
//Since it'll have none or one element..
if(Model.ItemList != null  && Model.ItemList.Any())
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ItemList.First())
}
```

Comment: 'Length' is not showing up in the intellisense list. Instead i had to do this: Model.ItemList.ToList().Count. but using the index it gave me this error msg: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<DataContext.GetItem_ListResult>'. Also, you mentioned 'in your foreach loop do this'. Do i have to add that for loop in the foreach of replace it with the for loop?

Comment: it contains more then 60 items. And the dbml generated the ISingleResult from the stored procedure. I don't know why because there are more then 1 items that are returned by the SP.

Comment: @Yustme you could try and change the CustomerModel in your dbml designer and make the type `List<GetItem_ListResult>` and then go with  the for loop. Also, does it work with a regular foreach?

Comment: it's not a CustomerModel, but a CustomModel. It combines 2 models so that i can make a strongly typed model for the view. Otherwise i have to pass 2 models to the View(), which is not possible. And changing the dbml would make everything undone once updated.

Comment: Forgot to mention that problem is not displaying the data in the view. That works just fine. All data is displayed just fine. But posting it to the controller is the problem after pressing the submit button. The parameter "cm" is always null. The data is lost, i get one record back and all values are either '0' or 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this blog post? http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ Steve covers editing lists in asp mvc.

Once your read that take a look at this nuget package http://nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem

Comment: i came across that blog. But he is using aspx, and i'm using razor engine.

Comment: The principle is exactly the same. I am using it in production razor based systems at the moment. The actual MVC infrastructure is the same.